# How to draw this motor diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want ideas on how to draw this diagram of an induction motor's stator. I do not know how to proceed with the teeth around the circumference of the inner circle.

Comment: I would start figuring out how to describe the teeth systematically. The arc between the teeth depends on the number of teeth as well as on the width of them. Think about how to draw a tooth pointing in some direction you are comfortable with (e.g. up) and then rotating and moving. You then connect the teeth with arcs using the two parameters width and number.
I think i would start by drawing, say, 4 teeth and figuring out the pattern. If you have that, you can draw the right number.

Use polar coordinates, this will simplify alot. You can also use relative polar coordinates, which is useful.

Answer (score 7):

I have to admit, the code could definitely be improved, but for now it does the job. I'll edit the answer in case I come up with something cleaner. Change `\def\n{24}` to change the number of teeth.

[image]

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{24} % <-- number of teeth, change this to change all

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (0,0) circle (4);
\draw (0,0) circle (5);

\foreach \angle in {1,...,\n}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\compute{\angle*360/\n}
\begin{scope}[rotate around={\compute:(O)}]
\coordinate (A) at (92:4); \coordinate (E) at (88:4);
\coordinate (B) at (91:3); \coordinate (D) at (89:3);
\coordinate (C) at (94:2.9);


\draw[fill=white, rounded corners=.5mm] ++(96:4) arc (96:92:4) -- (B) -- (C) arc (93:85:2.9) -- (D) -- (E) arc (88:84:4) -- (84:4.05) arc (84:96:4.05) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
}
\draw[white, line width=.65mm] (0,0) circle (4.04);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```